# Apache Installed in Non default location, how to restart?

Tags: centos, apache2

Apache is currently running in /usr/local/apache2/

However when i type systemctl status httpd.service i get the error message below.

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-05-19 10:27:29 BST; 8s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)   Process: 29368 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 29366 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 29366 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 19 10:27:29  httpd[29366]: (98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address [::]:80 
May 19 10:27:29  httpd[29366]: (98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80 
May 19 10:27:29  httpd[29366]: no listening sockets available, shutting down 
May 19 10:27:29  httpd[29366]: AH00015: Unable to open logs 
May 19 10:27:29  systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
May 19 10:27:29  kill[29368]: kill: cannot find process "" May 19 10:27:29 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 
May 19 10:27:29  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. 
May 19 10:27:29 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. 
May 19 10:27:29 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

How would i successfully restart the current running Apache in /usr/local/apache2/

Comment: Either there is a different systemd unit for your locally built apache httpd in addition to the one from the CentOS httpd rpm package, or your local apache wasn't started by systemd and you manage it differently.

Comment: I believe there is the default install of apache (which is off) and an install in /usr/local/apache2/ which is currently running. How would I go about restarting the one in /usr/local/apache2?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by doing the following;
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start

Answer (score 0):

As far you already answered on this question, I'll decribe what it was. You have working Apache, it listen on port 80, but doesn't have PID file. So systemctl try to start and fails. When you execute stop, systemctl kill running Apache process and then you start new process.